# How to add font Family attribute under Attributes in the graphical layout android studio

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, ubuntu-14.04

I use android studio to create an android app. I use as an OS Ubuntu 14.04.
In my app, I want to change the font, I follow the following step:

1. Right-click in the res folder and go to New > Android resource   directory.
2. In the Resource type list, I select font, and then I click OK
3. I add my font files in the font folder
4. After that, in the layout xml I set the fontFamily attribute to the font file that I want to access as the  following in textView component android:fontFamily="@font/cairo_extralight"

After that, the font doesn't change because we should change it also in the attributes of the graphical layout.But, when I go to the attributes in the graphical layout, I didn't found the fontfamily attribute under textAppearance property. 
I want to know why the fontfamily attribute does not exist in the list of proprety and how can I add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common problems you should check:

- `android:fontFamily` only works from API version 16. On Android versions below, the property will have no effect.
- Support for using `android:fontFamily` with your own fonts was added in Support Library v26 and Android Studio 3.0 (together with Android Gradle Plugin version 3.0). If you are using older versions of any of these, it will not work.
- If you have a custom *TextView*, make sure you extend *AppCompatTextView*. Otherwise no custom fonts will be used.
- When using custom views, make sure that the attributes, theme, and style are correctly propagated (when overriding constructors for example).
- Not all widgets support `android:FontFamily`. *TextView*, *EditText*, *Button*, and a few others do, but *Checkbox* and *Switch* don't. There you need to use `setTypeFace` in code instead.

Comment: I update the support library to v26, and now the font family appear in the list of the attributes that's good, but an error appear as the following: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTint' with config ''. error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTintMode' with config ''.

Comment: That means that somewhere in a library or in your own code you have defined the custom attribute 'iconTint'. In the new support lib, this has been added too, so there are now duplicate values for it. You should remove (or rename) the one from your own code, or update the libraries.